# Can "you've" be used as a possessive "have"?

Tags: contractions

Generally, "you've" is used in conjunction with another verb, such as "I see you've arrived" or "She asked if you've seen this".

Is it also acceptable to use "you've" without a second verb, using the "have" as possessive? ex: "I see you've a new car".

Comment: In the UK and elsewhere outside the USA, probly. In the USA, not so much.

Comment: What @John said. I'm not much good with the algebra, but I think [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+have+a+bone%3Aeng_us_2012%2FI%27ve+a+bone%3Aeng_us_2012%2CI+have+a+bone%3Aeng_gb_2012%2FI%27ve+a+bone%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28I%20have%20a%20bone%3Aeng_us_2012%20/%20I%20%27ve%20a%20bone%3Aeng_us_2012%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28I%20have%20a%20bone%3Aeng_gb_2012%20/%20I%20%27ve%20a%20bone%3Aeng_gb_2012%29%3B%2Cc0) means the US preference for the contracted version has increased a lot in recent decades.

Comment: Not only did it not pop up as a recommendation @JanusBahsJacquet, i actually created this account exclusively to ask this question after multiple googles came up with nothing. I suggest you keep your comments a bit more cordial, as these terse reactions only serve to hurt the community in the long run.

Comment: I'd be pretty sure ***You've got mail*** was at the very least *popularised* by Americans, even if they didn't actually "invent" it.

Comment: @BenRoux I’ve just tested, and—strange as it is—you’re absolutely right! None of the other questions about the topic pop up in the “Questions that may already have your answer” list. However, at least four of them _do_ appear in the “Similar questions” box on the right-hand side of the screen when typing in the question. I apologise if my comment came off as brash, but it is the responsibility of the asker of a question to show that they have done some basic research to find an answer to their question, and reviewing the “Similar questions” box is a basic and integral part of doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not in my dialect of American English.  And even worse is trying to contract a causative have:

> *Be sure you've your papers turned in on time.
>   *I see that you've your mortgage all paid off.
>   *We've our accountant get the data he needs on line.

Comment: I agree the sentences sound rather odd, but i i haven't found a rule indicating it is literally improper. I suppose it may be improper simply by virtue of cultural norms.

Comment: I don't know what "literally improper" means.  What sort of "improper" could there be besides what is imposed by cultural norms?

Comment: Non-auxiliary have is commonly contracted in Britain in expressions like '... we've a new car now'; '... they've a bigger house than we have'.